# Excel built-in or VBA function to format part of the text (e.g. color)

Tags: excel, function, vba, string-formatting

I need to format a color (or bold text ...) of first row of multirow text cell. So e.g. I got

=myfunction (firstLine, secondLine), which then produces (inside one cell)

```
    firstLine (vbLf)
    secondLine
```

but i need it to produce

```
    **firstLine** (vbLf)
    secondLine
```

(the first line is bold)
So formating just a portion of a string but inside a VBA function. I could do it inside Sub with something like

```
    lngPos = InStr(myCell.Value, vbLf)
    With myCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=lngPos - 1).Font
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
    End With
```

but i cannot find a way how  to do it inside a function, if it is even possible.

Answer (score 2):

its not possible to do anything but return a value from a user defined function (UDF). You can trigger a worksheet event with the change however and then update data. Add this in the module for the relevant sheet. Change Range("J6:J10") to the range you need to monitor and add the bold / any additional code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J6:J10")) Is Nothing Then

        ' do something on the cells

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger the update via code as opposed to wait for a direct change (and formatting a cell does not trigger a `Change` event) then you could force it via a simple sub

You should always disable `Events` when working with the `Change` event to avoid unintended loops. While formatting won't trigger the event itself, further code changes/additions could do so - good practice to reduce this risk

**normal module**

```
Sub MakeUpdate()
Sheets(1).[a1:a10].Formula = Sheets(1).[a1:a10].Formula
End Sub
```

**in the sheet code of Sheet(1)**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = Intersect(Target, [a1:a10])
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With
For Each rng2 In rng1.Cells
rng2.Characters(1, InStr(rng2.Value, vbLf) - 1).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
Next
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```